# How to sample records from many different associations in SQL?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have a fairly complex SQL database schema to include in this post (and I am working with [knex](http://knexjs.org/), a direct SQL builder in Node.js), but in essence you have this:

- Words have many WordTranscriptions
- WordTranscriptions have the text string, and many Properties
- Properties can be integer, boolean, string, or json (4 different tables), with a value field, and a key/name field.
- Words have Properties to, and a Language, and a weight (how high up on the page I want them to show up ideally, their sort order).

So I am querying for a single word. I have it working so I can find all the WordTranscriptions for a word, and all their properties. Next I want to return *with the word* a list of related words, which have a Property containing the same integer value (like if the property is "wordLength", I want to find words with the same length). In my case it is more complicated than just word length, such as the number of each character in the string, or its various gematria values, and other things, so too dynamic and too numerous of properties to just store them on the Word or WordTranscription table. It depends on the language, the encoding, the transformation operations performed on the words, etc..

So I would like to now return 100 related words, but pluck 20 from the same language (English), 10 from 5 similar languages (French, Spanish, etc.), and 5 from 6 from unrelated languages (English to Chinese). The word has a language id on it. How do I generally go about querying for such a layout of words? Can it be done in one simple query, or must I make multiple queries of some sort?

I don't need to get a precise answer, just a general "how to approach this problem" solution. If the words are sorted by weight, the global weights might have English as higher than Chinese and Spanish, but I want some of those to appear. I guess I could change the weights, but that wouldn't guarantee that I get 5 Chinese ones, sorted by their weight. I can only see this being possible by making multiple queries, one for each of the 12 languages. But maybe there is some optimizations I can make somehow, precomputing queries? But I don't think I should precompute queries as there could be a million possible words, and you'd have a million precomputed queries. I don't know what the right general approach is here, hoping for a quick explanation of how it should be done.

Ideally this would be a fast query to not have any noticeable page load time.

If it is at all helpful, [here](https://gist.github.com/lancejpollard/0fc3895bddd0cc26d3e0bf06c511f7ea) is the main query code I have so far. It starts at `getByValue`.

How could I essentially say, "Select 100 records, where language_id is in [1,2,3,4,5], where lang1 gets 20, lang 2,3,4 get 10, and lang 5 gets 5, where each chunk is sorted by weight"?

Comment: Please tag which database system you are investigating with.

Comment: Are you planning to return the results to the client as common objects or put a bit of logic in a stored procedure? Let's say you return 200K rows to the client and only 250 are used, that is a waste on both sides. Can your client apis' make use of paging, filtering, etc. which is best suited for a RDMS?

Comment: Yes the APIs will be able to use paging/filtering of some sort, but I don't know how yet. We will only return the minimal set of results to the client.